# How to filter the output when you click "Run" in Intellij IDEA Edu?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I'm trying to learn Java using JetBrains Academy (Hyperskill.org). While doing my first task and running it for the first time, I get lots of text in the Run tool window. I thought that was a one time thing (never coded in Java before, only Python) so I rerun the code but the same thing happens. This really triggers me to frustration that there is no way to filter through this. Please help, I just want the output of the main file's code (Circled in screenshot).

Running Intellij IDEA Edu by the way.

[image: Run tool window output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle-based IDE projects use Gradle to actually build and run your code. This is the output you would get when running it from command line by Gradle.

To switch to the IDE's builder and runner set **IntelliJ IDEA** for Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Build and run using** option.

See also [Configure the build and run actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#delegate_build_gradle) documentation topic for more details.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped. -1 was not from me.